# My email sends but has no table headers

Tags: c#

//This is my button send event//
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
    //This is my html file that sends successfully but has no table Headers//

```
                string mailBody = "<HTML><Body><table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";

                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
                {
                    mailBody += "<tr>";
                    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        mailBody += "<td style='color:blue;'>" + cell.Value + "</td>";
                    }
                    mailBody += "</tr>";
                }
                mailBody += "</table></Body></HTML>";
//The html form ends here//


                Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
                mail.To = txtTo.Text;
                mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
                //mail.Body = mailBody;
                mail.HTMLBody = mailBody;

                mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
                ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
                MessageBox.Show("Your Message has been successfully sent.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

//My email sends the data in the body but the table for the datagridview does not show the table headers.//

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. If you want to use HTML in the email body then tell it so `mail.IsBodyHtml = true;`

Comment: Your question doesn't have much clarity. Please edit the question to add sample input and the expected out. For example when you pass a specific HTML how you are expecting to see mail

Comment: Hi All. My code does send an Email. The body is HTML and it shows the Data that is pulled from the datagridview but the are no Table headers. e.g Every column has a header. I am trying to show the column headers along with the cells that are pulled.

Comment: You don't add any headers when defining your table. I'm sure you can use your favourite search engine to locate a guide on the HTML code for tables with headers, there are countless resources available...

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking for an HTML header tag, you would be looking to use the TH element, similar to below:

```html
<TABLE BORDER='1'>
<TR><TH>Table Header 1</TH><TH>Table Header 2</TH></TR>
<TR><TD>Table Cell 1</TD><TD>Table Cell 2</TD></TR>
</TABLE>
```

Without further information, we're unable to really provide much input here - we need expected input/output and at this point we can only simply assume.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mailBody = "<HTML><Head><Body><table width='100%' style='border:Solid 1px Black;'>";

        foreach (DataGridViewColumn Column in dataGridView3.Columns)
        {
            mailBody += "<td style=font -size:100%'><b>" + Column.HeaderText + "</b></td>";
        }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView3.Rows)
            {
                mailBody += "<tr style=font - size:150 % '>";
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    mailBody += "<td style='color:black;'>" + cell.Value + "</td>";
                }
                mailBody += "</tr>";
            }
        mailBody += "</Head></table></Body></HTML>";

        Outlook._Application _app = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)_app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        try
        {
            mail.To = txtTo.Text;
            mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
            mail.HTMLBody=mailBody;

            mail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceNormal;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)mail).Send();
            MessageBox.Show("Your Message has been successfully sent.", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            txtTo.Clear();
            txtSubject.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

//That is what finally worked for me.